What is the $\sigma$-algebra with which the variables are measurable?
Many variants of the following problem appeared on this site:
"Alice types $n$ (for fixed $n$) characters on a page, each of them being a typo with probability $q$.
Then, she runs the spell-checker, which detects each typo independently with probability $p$.
Let $X$ be the number of typos, and $N$ be the number of detected typos. Prove $\mathbb{E}(N|X)=pX$ etc."
I would like to find an explicit space with $\sigma$-algebra on which $X,N$ are measurable.
Below I show my try, but it seems to be a totally wrong approach.
My try: $\Omega=\{typo,correct\}^n$ with $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ with probability $\mathbb{P}=\mu^{\otimes n}$ where $\mu(typo)=q, \mu(correct)=1-q$ with $\mu$ a probability on $\{typo,correct\}$. This is how I interpret the first sentence of the problem, and then $X$ is clear how to do, count nr of element "typo" appearing in sequence, while I have no clue how to even realize $N$ as a variable.
